Power BI - Average Daily Data
I have the attached excel spreadsheet which I have loaded into Power BI, I am trying to create a graph with
average time by month but can't figure it out! How do I do this please? 
The first column has data by day and the second column has a time every day. I need to average these out by month.
Tried multiple Power BI techniques

convert the time to a duration, then average that. If you have to, use SUMMARIZE() to do it. then graph that.

You can do the following:

Create column to convert OOS hh:mm:ss to total hours.
Create measure to average hours.
(Optional) Convert back to formatted value (hh:mm:ss).

1. Create Total Hours Column
OSS_Hours = 
var durationToPath = SUBSTITUTE( 'Table'[OOS hh:mm:ss], ":", "|") //converts duration into a path

var durationHour = PATHITEM(durationToPath, 1) //retrieves hours from path
var durationMinutes = PATHITEM(durationToPath, 2) //retrieves minutes from path
var durationSeconds = PATHITEM(durationToPath, 3) //retrieves seconds from path

var durationToHours = durationHour + durationMinutes/60 + durationMinutes/3600 //Converts minutes and seconds to hours

return ROUND(durationToHours,2)

2. Create Average Hours Measure
Average_Hours = CALCULATE(AVERAGE('Table'[OSS_Hours]))

3. (Optional) Convert back to hh:mm:ss
Average_Formatted = 

var averageHours = CALCULATE(AVERAGE('Table'[OSS_Hours]))

var hours = ROUNDDOWN(averageHours, 0) //retrieve # of full hours
var remainingMinutes = (averageHours - hours) * 60 //retrieve remaining minutes

var minutes = ROUNDDOWN(remainingMinutes, 0) //retrieve # of full minutes
var remainingSeconds= ROUND((remainingMinutes - minutes) * 60, 0) //retrieve remaining seconds

var formatH = FORMAT(hours, "00") //00 format
var formatM = FORMAT(minutes, "00") //00 format
var formatS = FORMAT(remainingSeconds, "00") //00 format
 
var formatHours = formatH & ":" & formatM & ":" & formatS //format hh:mm:ss

return formatHours

